# MS Word VBA: Get document's attached template

Tags: vba, templates, ms-word

(Using Windows 10 and MS Word 2016. Global templates are: Normal.dotx and Autoload.dotm. Attached template to some docs is: Reference.dotx)

Hello everyone,

I'm having problems in VBA getting the attached template of a document.

I have a global template that loads when I load MS Word, called Autoload.dotm. But, for some specific documents, they use an attached template, which is not the global template (Autload.dotm) or the regular template (Normal.dotx). This attached template is called Reference.dotx.

So I use ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate. But this returns Autoload.dotm, not Reference.dotx. I need to find out if the attached template defined in Developer->Document Template->Templates tab->Document Template is Reference.dotx. (Don't think it makes a difference, but the "Automatically update document styles" checkbox is checked.) Does anyone know how I can find if a document uses Reference.dotx? I don't need any of the global templates returned.

The code I'm using to try to get the attached template is simple:

```
    If (ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate = "Reference.dotx") Then
        PrepareDocument_enabled = True
    End If
```

Comment: Could it be the path that is wrong? You can use `AttachedTemplate.Name and .Path`. Have you tried `Debug.print activedocument.attachedtemplate.name` or `.path`?

Comment: Nah. That unfortunately just returns Normal.dotm. It doesn't even return the global template I added in. :/

Comment: And that is exactly the issue(?). It cannot find the document reference.dotx.

Comment: Holy wow, that was exactly it! I recently changed computers, so the paths were messed up, and the only thing I was paying attention to when I checked the template was the filename. I put blinders to the path. Thanks a ton for clearing that up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help you? It will show the template used.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim strPath As String
    strPath = Dialogs(wdDialogToolsTemplates).Template
    MsgBox strPath
End Sub
```

Otherwise, you can use this to change the template

```
Sub ChangeAttachedTemplate()
Dim oDoc As Document
Dim oTemplate As Template
Dim strTemplatePath As String

Set oDoc = ActiveDocument

If oDoc.Type = wdTypeTemplate Then Exit Sub

Set oTemplate = oDoc.AttachedTemplate

Debug.Print oTemplate.FullName

' Path is probably: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\
If InStr(UCase(oTemplate.FullName), UCase("Path of the template")) > 0 Then
     oDoc.AttachedTemplate = "PATH TO TEMPLATE" & "TEMPLATE NAME.dotm"
End If
End Sub
```